# Ruby on rails db fetching

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
while($table1=mysql_feach_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `table1`")))
{
$table2=mysql_feach_assoc(mysql_query("select table2_id from `table2` where field='$table1[field1]'"))
echo $table2['table2_id'];
}
```

I need a Ruby on rails code equivalent to this php code without using table joining.

Comment: Perhaps you could format that code snippet?

Comment: Your question feels like you're expecting us to do all the work. You could show us what you tried. Did you define models? If yes, paste them in your question.

Comment: First of all: welcome to StackOverflow :-). I realize this is your first, but I'm sorry to say this isn't a real question. Have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give examples to explain better what you want, but an equivalent may be:

```
table1Rows = table1.all
table2Rows = table2.find(:all, :select => "table2_id", :conditions => ["field in (?)", table1.map{|row| row.field1}])
table2Rows.each { |row| #do_stuff_here}
```

But if your tables are related, you even easier than that:
Let's say table2 is employees and table1 is departments (and one department can have more employees)

```
departments = Department.all
departments.do |department|
department.employees.each { |emp| #do_stuff_with_emp}
```

Answer (score 2):

We won't do the work for you. You need to put some effort into it and then we'll be able to help.

However if you're clueless about Ruby on Rails, this can get you started with ActiveRecord - Rails' ORM framework:

1. [ActiveRecord Query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)
2. [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

If you're looking for something more low level, without the need to create models, and talking directly to the database such as in your example, you can read the [mysql2 driver documentation](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) for a quick start.